# Can not create multiple instances of a class

Tags: php, object

I am writing a PHP application in which I am experiancing a strange bug.  I have a class, called Permission that is represented as such:

```
//Permissions class
class Permission {
    //Permission name
    protected $permission_name = "";

    //Constructor method
    function __construct($name) {
        //Get global reference for variables used here
        global $permission_name;

        //Save the permission name
        $permission_name = $name;

        echo("<br>" . $name . "<br>");
    }

    //Compare permissions
    function compare($permission) {
        //Get global reference for variables used here
        global $permission_name;

        //Break down the permissions into arrays
        $permission_a_data = explode(".", $permission_name);
        $permission_b_data = explode(".", $permission);

        //Iterate through the permission values
        foreach($permission_a_data as $index=>$perm) {
            //Check for a wildcard permission
            if($perm == "*") {
                //User has wildcard permission
                return true;
            }
            //Check if permission has ended
            if(!isSet($permission_b_data[$index])) {
                //User does not have adequate permission
                return false;
            }
            //Check if permission is different
            if($permission_b_data[$index] != $perm) {
                //Permissions differ
                return false;
            }
        }

        //If application reaches this point, permissions are identical
        return true;
    }

    //Get the name
    function get_name() {
        //Get global reference for objects used here
        global $permission_name;
        //Return the name
        return $permission_name;
    }
}
```

And I have some code elsewhere in the application like such:

```
$permission1 = new Permission("This.is.a.test");
$permission2 = new Permission("test.a.is.This");
echo("<br>DEBUG:<br>");
echo($permission1->get_name() . "<br>");
echo($permission2->get_name() . "<br>");
```

However the second piece of code always prints:

```
DEBUG:
test.a.is.This
test.a.is.This
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `global`? You're missing a fundamental piece of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

It's overwriting `$permission_name` every time you call a `new` instance because inside `function __construct` `$permission_name` is `global`, and `->get_name()` is returning the same `global` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `global $permission_name` lines from your class.

you can refer to the current instance of the class using `$this`.so, you can use `$this->permission_name` to access the `$permission_name` of the current instance.something like,

```
class Permission {
    //Permission name
    protected $permission_name = "";

    //Constructor method
    function __construct($name) {

        $this->permission_name = $name;

    }

    function compare($permission) {

        //Break down the permissions into arrays
        $permission_a_data = explode(".", $this->permission_name);

        //....
    }

    function get_name() {

        //Return the name
        return $this->permission_name;
   }

}
```